# Using past tense for possible event in the future?

Tags: past-tense, conditional-future

Can anyone help me with this? Here is a sentence:

> I wanted to check and see **if there was** anything you need before I **went** on my maternity leave.

It's from The Office. And she asks the question before going on maternity leave.

I really don't understand the usage of the verbs in their past tense form in this sentence.  I've reviewed all the rules of conditional statements, but I couldn't find any useful information that can help me analyze this sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common type of solecism. I suspect that it happens like this:

As they speak, the person is recounting the sequence of events from the viewpoint of some future time after going on leave. Hence, were they already on leave they might reasonably say "I wanted to check and see if there was *anything you need* {acting as a noun phrase rather than a present tense structure} before I went on my maternity leave."

There is a hint of reason in this particular example because - all being well - that future is inevitable, looms large in the woman's mind, and may well dominate her modes of thought and expression.

Of course, when they move the thought to the time when they are actually asking if anything is needed, and do not modify their tenses accordingly, it comes out all wrong and irritates folk like you and me. The suspicion of a present tense "need" within the sentence does not help.

A related sort of thing often happens in surgeries or when collecting goods from shops. You turn up and the receptionist frequently says "*What was the name?*". She or he is asking the question from a viewpoint that looks back to the time an appointment may have been made rather than asking directly in the present "*What is your name?*".
(It is courteous to remember that usage takes precedence over grammar so I have so far resisted the temptation to snippily rejoin "*The same as it is now*".)

Comment: This reminds me of the waiter who asks the customer at the end of the meal "Did you want dessert?" and the customer answers "I still do."

Answer (score 0):

Also, when asking a question people quite often say "I wanted to know" or "I wondered" (when, of course, they still want to know at the time of asking), perhaps thinking back to the moment when they decided to telephone or to come and ask. The other past tenses then follow on from that.